# Iterating through nested array of objects

Tags: array, json, typescript

I have the following JSON list of objects, and I'm able to find the required object, and pass it back to the caller, given the `id`. Everything works fine, I'm just wondering if there's a better (more efficient) way to return the node. I'm open to using a 3rd party tool like `lodash`.

JSON payload:

```
{
  "_expanded": true,
  "_canDrop": false,
  "_id": "-1",
  "_name": "root",
  "_children": [
    {
      "_expanded": true,
      "_canDrop": false,
      "_id": "1",
      "_name": "Child 1",
      "_children": [
        {
          "_expanded": true,
          "_canDrop": false,
          "_id": "1-1",
          "_name": "Child 1-1",
          "_children": [
            {
              "_expanded": false,
              "_canDrop": false,
              "_id": "1-1-1",
              "_name": "Child 1-1-1",
              "_children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "_expanded": false,
          "_canDrop": false,
          "_id": "1-2",
          "_name": "Child 1-2",
          "_children": []
        },
        {
          "_expanded": false,
          "_canDrop": false,
          "_id": "1-3",
          "_name": "Child 1-3",
          "_children": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "_expanded": true,
      "_canDrop": false,
      "_id": "2",
      "_name": "Child 2",
      "_children": [
        {
          "_expanded": false,
          "_canDrop": false,
          "_id": "2-2",
          "_name": "Child 2-2",
          "_children": []
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Find method:

```
public findNode = (id: any): TreeNode => {
    let result = null;
    if (this._id === id) {
      result = this;
    } else {
      if (this._children.length > 0) {
        for (let index = 0; index <= this._children.length - 1; index++) {
          result = this._children[index].findNode(id);
          if (result) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method already looks good! I would only make a couple small changes to the logic as follows:

1. The `if (this._children.length > 0)` isn't necessary as the for loop
   will make the check for you
2. Instead of using a standard for loop, I would prefer a `for..of`
   loop. Typescript will transpile this so it will work in any
   environment
3. I prefer early returns to nested statements. Because of this, I
   would recommend storing the `result` variable in as small a block as
   possible

With these changes:

```ts
public findNode = (id: any): TreeNode => {
  if (this._id === id) {
    return this;
  }

  for (const child of this._children) {
    const result = child.findNode(id);
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Also, here's a couple Typescript specific notes:

1. Avoid `any` like the plague. When you use `any` you are telling
   typescript to effectively ignore any mistakes in your code. Given
   your data structure, it looks like `id` should be of type `string`
2. I highly recommend turning on
   [`strictNullChecks`](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/strictNullChecks.html).
   This will help prevent a large class of errors
3. Methods are public by default in Typescript, with this in mind I
   recommend dropping the `public` modifier in most cases as it is redundant. However, this does not apply if you are working on a team with developers who generally work with other languages as it could lead to confusion in the team. For example, in C# the default is
   that all methods are `private`

With these changes:

```ts
findNode = (id: string): TreeNode | null => {
  if (this._id === id) {
    return this;
  }

  for (const child of this._children) {
    const result = child.findNode(id);
    if (result) {
      return result;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. The return statement at each condition level is far more elegant. It works really well - many thanks @Gerrit0. As a matter of interest though, what would the `TreeNode | null =>` accomplish?

Comment: The `TreeNode | null` only makes sense if you turn on `strictNullChecks`. If you turn on `strictNullChecks` and don't explicitly define the return type as potentially being null the compiler won't be happy.